# Error: Request failed with status code 400 (Axios, Graphql, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, axios, graphql, webhooks

I made a server that handles webhook events from a service called Persona that verifies and collects identity information. Everytime I get a webhook call from Persona, I want to do 2 things: I want to take store some of the data from the webhook payload in my Mongoose database AND I want a notification to pop up in discord. If the information taken from the payload already exists in the mongoose db, then I want a notification on discord saying "user already exists". Otherwise, "new user".

My problem is that my axios request seems to be failing after getting the webhook call from Persona. This is my code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require("axios").default;
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Event = require('./models/event');


const app = express();
const port = 3000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: buildSchema(`
  type Event {
    _id: ID!
    lastName: String!
    firstName: String!  
    birthdate: String!
    address: String!
  }

  input EventInput {
    lastName: String!
    firstName: String!  
    birthdate: String!
    address: String!
  }

  type RootQuery {
    events: [Event!]!

  }

  type RootMutation {
    createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): Event
  }


  schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
  }
  `),
  rootValue: {
    events: () => {
      return Event.find()
        .then(events => {
          return events.map(event => {
            return { ...event._doc, _id: event.id };
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
    createEvent: (args) => {
      return Event.find({lastName: args.eventInput.lastName, firstName: args.eventInput.firstName, birthdate: args.eventInput.birthdate})
      .then( event => {
        if (event) {
          const content = `User already exists: ${args.eventInput.firstName},${args.eventInput.firstName}. Birthdate: 
          ${args.eventInput.birthdate}. address: ${args.eventInput.address}`;

          axios
          .post(process.env.DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL, {
            content: content,
  
          })
          .then((discordResponse) => {
            console.log("Success!");
          })
        }
        const content = `New User. address: ${args.eventInput.address}`;

        axios
        .post(process.env.DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL, {
          content: content,

        })
        .then((discordResponse) => {
          console.log("Success!");
        })

        return event
        .save()
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          return { ...result._doc, _id: result._doc._id.toString() };
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }); 
      })

  }
},
graphiql: true
})
);

app.post("/", (req, res) => {

    const nameOfEvent = req.body.data.attributes.name;
    const firstName = req.body.data.attributes.payload.data.attributes.nameFirst;
    const lastName = req.body.data.attributes.payload.data.attributes.nameLast;
    const birthdate = req.body.data.attributes.payload.data.attributes.birthdate;
    const address = req.body.data.attributes.payload.data.attributes.fields.address.value;
    if (nameOfEvent == "inquiry.completed") {

axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: {
    query: `
      mutation {
        createEvent(eventInput: {lastName: "${lastName}", firstName: "${firstName}", birthdate: "${birthdate}", address: "${address}}) {
          lastName
          firstName
        }
      }
    `
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
      throw new Error('Failed!');
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(resData => {
    console.log(resData);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}})
;

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500)
  res.send({ error: error })
  console.error(error.stack)
  next(error)
})


mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.nrtrssh.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

This is my event schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const eventSchema = new Schema({
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  birthdate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

This was I got in my terminal:

```
  config: {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"query":"\\n      mutation {\\n        createEvent(eventInput: {lastName: \\"SAMPLE\\", firstName: \\"ALEXANDER J\\", birthdate: \\"1977-07-17\\", address: \\"0x98433A5F2127b48Ae71f638e81f99b211e1F8ab6}) {\\n          lastName\\n          firstName\\n        }\\n      }\\n    "}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
      'Content-Length': 266
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 262,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'POST /graphql HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 266\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/graphql',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 266,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST,GET,OPTIONS',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '99',
      etag: 'W/"63-STfhlTxeoEFxDo5wbBoiR3lYMrg"',
      date: 'Sat, 21 Jan 2023 03:44:04 GMT',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
      method: 'post',
      data: '{"query":"\\n      mutation {\\n        createEvent(eventInput: {lastName: \\"SAMPLE\\", firstName: \\"ALEXANDER J\\", birthdate: \\"1977-07-17\\", address: \\"0x98433A5F2127b48Ae71f638e81f99b211e1F8ab6}) {\\n          lastName\\n          firstName\\n        }\\n      }\\n    "}',
      headers: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'POST /graphql HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 266\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/graphql',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: { errors: [Array] }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what is in   `data: { errors: [Array] }` ?